# How to find an element using xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, findelement, best-buy-api

I am new to coding and I am trying to create a checkout bot. I am using selenium to help me do this. So far my code works up until the checkout I can't seem to get my bot to click the checkout button.

This is what I get when I inspect the checkout button.

```
   <a href="https://www.bestbuy.ca/identity/global/signin?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bestbuy.ca%2Fcheckout%2F%3Fqit%3D1%23%2Fen-ca%2Fshipping%2FON%2FM4W&lang=en-CA&contextId=checkout" class="button_E6SE9 primary_1oCqK continueToCheckout_3Dgpe regular_1jnnf" data-automation="continue-to-checkout"> == $0
```

I have tried

```
find_element_by_class_name("continueToCheckout_3Dgpe")
find_element_by_xpath( '//*[@class="continueToCheckout_3Dgpe"]' ).click()
findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='https://www.bestbuy.ca/identity/global/signin?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bestbuy.ca%2Fcheckout%2F%3Fqit%3D1%23%2Fen-ca%2Fshipping%2FON%2FM4W&lang=en-CA&contextId=checkout']")).click();
find_element_by_partial_link_text('https://www.bestbuy.ca/identity/global/signin?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bestbuy.ca%2Fcheckout%2F%3Fqit%3D1%23%2Fen-ca%2Fshipping%2FON%2FM4W&lang=en-CA&contextId=checkout')
find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="https://www.bestbuy.ca/identity/global/signin?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bestbuy.ca%2Fcheckout%2F%3Fqit%3D1%23%2Fen-ca%2Fshipping%2FON%2FM4W&lang=en-CA&contextId=checkout"]')
find_element(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://www.bestbuy.ca/identity/global/signin?redirectUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bestbuy.ca%2Fcheckout%2F%3Fqit%3D1%23%2Fen-ca%2Fshipping%2FON%2FM4W&lang=en-CA&contextId=checkout']"))
```

None seems to work and doesn't click the checkout button. If any idea on how to fix this it would be helpful! Thank you :)

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @BuddyBobIII I am assuming so. I have it on a while loop that if checkout fails it will restart the program which is what's happening each time I get to checkout. I tried other buttons like Paypal and visa check out on the same page and they all were able to click just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-automation='continue-to-checkout']").click()
```

Would click the a tag with the attribute continue to checkout. Now you might need to wait if you switch to that page or etc.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@data-automation='continue-to-checkout']"))).click()
```

Comment: This should work. Was about to suggest the same thing.

Comment: Still giving me an error :(( Thats alright. I figured out different check out methods and that works just as fine thanks for the help tho!